# Pattern matching with two values of inductive type at the same index

Tags: pattern-matching, coq, dependent-type

Why does the following not type-check (coq-8.5pl3)? Pattern matching seems to forget that `u` and `v` have the same type.

```
Inductive X : Type -> Type :=
| XId : forall a, X a -> X a
| XUnit : X unit.

Fixpoint f {a : Type} (x : X a) (y : X a) : a :=
  match x, y with
  | XId _ u, XId _ v => f u v
  | XUnit, _ => tt
  | _, XUnit => tt
  end.
```

Error message:

```
Error:
In environment
f : forall a : Type, X a -> X a -> a
a : Type
x : X a
y : X a
T : Type
u : X T
y0 : X T
T0 : Type
v : X T0
The term "v" has type "X T0"
while it is expected to have type "X T".
```

Comment: Try searching for "convoy pattern" [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bcoq%5d%20convoy%20pattern) or in [CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/MoreDep.html)

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Anton Trunov's hint of "convoy pattern", I managed to make a version that compiles.

```
Fixpoint f {a : Type} (x : X a) : X a -> a :=
  match x in X a return X a -> a with
  | XId b u => fun y => match y in X b return X b -> b with
                        | XId c v => fun u => f u v
                        | XUnit => fun _ => tt
                        end u
  | XUnit => fun _ => tt
  end.
```